# Did Gandalf ever lose a staff before, or is it purely a Jackson invention?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, gandalf

So in the **Jacksonverse movies** we see Gandalf losing his staff tons of times.

I believe, in the movies, he loses his staff to the Necromancer (The Hob.), and Saruman (LOTR-1st), and the Witch-King (LOTR-3rd). I don't remember any more movie instances where Gandalf loses his staff but I'm not asking about that. I could use a quote in the novels if Gandalf does lose his staff.

> 1. [image: 1st] 
>  2. [image: 2nd] 
>  3. [image: 3rd]

In canon... ***is there evidence to show that Gandalf loses his staff while in middle-earth, or is the whole 'losing-a-staff' thing a Jackson invention?***

Answer (score 40):

He loses his original staff (by breaking it) in his fight with the Balrog.

> At that moment Gandalf lifted his staff, and crying aloud he smote the bridge before him. **The staff broke asunder and fell from his hand**. A blinding sheet of white flame sprang up. The bridge cracked. Right at the Balrog's feet it broke, and the stone upon which it stood crashed into the gulf, while the rest remained, poised, quivering like a tongue of rock thrust out into emptiness.
>
> <sub><sup>*The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring*, Book II, Chapter V, The Bridge of Khazad-Dum</sup></sub>

*That's it*, really. He gets a new one after he's resurrected and doesn't [lose that one](https://m.youtube.com/watch?gl=SG&hl=en-GB&v=2TTB5t_4Nlc). **The movies feature many of his staffs breaking, but in the books, it happens only one time.**

So Peter Jackson didn't invent Gandalf's staff breaking.

Gandalf's new staff after the fight with the Balrog in the books:

> Well met, I say again!' said the old man, coming towards them. When he was a few feet away, he stood, stooping over his staff, with his head thrust forward, peering at them from under his hood.
>
> <sub><sup>*The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers*, Book III, Chapter V, The White Rider</sup></sub>

Comment: He doesn't lose it, he just breaks it :P

Comment: @Edlothiad I don't reckon he kept the fragments and taped the staff back together, do you? ;-)

Comment: Then he left it behind! Although this is peculiar. I believe Alan Lee's drawing of Balrog v Gandalf atop Zirakzigil had Mith carrying a staff. Never mind a complete and utter lie

Comment: I gave you a +1, but your last line in bold kind of contradicts the rest of the answer. Perhaps better to say that in the books his staff was broken/destroyed only that one occasion, not the numerous times we see on film.

Comment: he would't be able to perform spells if he had taped it back together. He would risk his charms backfiring and loosing his memory. I am sure sure he bought a new one.

Comment: @Edlothiad [trust Ted Nasmith](http://www.tednasmith.com/tolkien/gandalf-and-the-balrog-upon-celebdil/)!

Comment: Always, with my life!

Comment: @user13267 we never get an indication that Gandalf's staff is any more than just a stick of wood that he uses to channel his power. It may not have any special properties.

Comment: He died and was sent back from the afterlife, and the stick of wood he is carrying is the issue?

Comment: I'll add that it was pretty climactic when Gandalf broke Saruman's staff, so a wizard losing his staff seems to be a pretty big deal.

Comment: @Voronwë is that Glamdring?

Comment: @Neithan To go along with that, Gandalf says in The Fellowship that he has to start with something to do magic. A hardy staff seems like a useful starter for a few spells.

Comment: Given that the book blithely refers to the new one as "his staff", its probably fair to say Tolkien didn't consider the acquisition of a new staff after the first one broke to be a big deal. So its also likely the staves themselves aren't really that big of a deal, and any old stick the right length and shape will do for him.

Comment: @Quasi_Stomach indeed that is Glamdring.

Answer (score 10):

Pulling from memory, when Gandalf confronts Saruman at Orthanc after the Ents drown Isengard, Gandalf holds out his hand and says "Saruman, your staff is broken" at which point Saruman's staff does indeed break. This seems to indicate that the staff is at least a symbol of their power, if not a channel for it. I therefore conclude that the loss of the staff is a seriously big deal for the Istari, and would not be a commonplace occurrence.

Again, drawing from memory, I believe there is an essay on the nature of the Istari in *Unfinished Tales* that says they arrived in Middle Earth in the guise of elder men, bent with age and carrying staves. If so, they wouldn't have been able to roll around to the nearest walking stick shop for a replacement, leading to my general perspective that they would avoid losing their staff even to the cost of their physical form.

The only referenced loss of Gandalf's own staff is during the confrontation with the Balrog. I can recall no other.